# Prove that $\sum_{x\in I}\delta_x$ diverges if $\delta_x>0$ and $I$ is more then countable.

Tags: analysis, probability-theory

Take $F:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ s.t. $F$ is continous from the right, not decreasing, $\lim_{x\to-\infty}F(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to+\infty}F(x)=1$.

Call $I:=\{x\in\Bbb R\;:\;F\;\; \mbox{is not continous in}\;\; x\}$; I have to show that $I$ is at most countable.

Now, if by contradiction $I$ is more than countable, then it would have the power of continuum.

Call then $F(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0^+}F(x)$ and $\lambda_{x_0}=\lim_{x\to x_0^-}F(x)$. Clear that $F(x_0)>\lambda_{x_0}\;\forall x_0\in I$.

Hence, named $\delta_{x}:=F(x)-\lambda_{x}$, it will be $\delta_{x}>0\;\forall x\in I$ so we can consider $(\delta_x)_{x\in I}$ which is a more then countable family of strictly positive numbers.

Now observe that $\lim_{x\to+\infty}F(x)\ge\sum_{x\in I}\delta_x$.

I think that the last sum diverges, which allows me to reach the contradiction and conclude, but I'm not able to treat with sums over more than countable objects. I tried in many ways to show this divergence, but I didn't went anywhere.

Can someone help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $\sum\limits_{x\in I}\delta_x$ is finite, then $n\sum\limits_{x\in I}\delta_x\geqslant\sum\limits_{x\in I}n\delta_x\mathbf 1_{n\delta_x\geqslant1}\geqslant\#\{x\in I\mid n\delta_x\geqslant1\}$. Hence, every set $\{x\in I\mid n\delta_x\geqslant1\}$ is finite, which implies that their union $\{x\in I\mid \delta_x\ne0\}$ is at most countable.